# Is the intersection a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have the subsets 
$$
V:=\left \{\left. \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}\ \right| x_1=0\right \}, \ \ \ W:=\left \{\left. \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}\ \right| x_2=2\right \}
$$ 
$V$ is a subspace and $W$ is an affine subspace.

I want to determine the intersection and check if it is a (affine) subspace or not.

We have the following:

\begin{align*}
V\cap W&=\left \{ \left. \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}\ \right|  x_1=0\right \}\cap \left \{\left. \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}\ \right| x_2=2\right \}\ \ 
& =\left\{\left. \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix} \ \right| x_1=0, x_2=2\right \}\\ & =\left \{\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}\right \}
\end{align*}

We can show that the set $S=\left \{\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}\right \}$ is a subspace and so the intersection $V\cap W$ is an affine subspace.

Is that correct and complete?

Or is the an other (better) way to show that?

Comment: For me, it's quite fine. With the same method, you can prove that the intersection of two affine subspaces is an affine subspace – a more general result.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but your conclusion could be clearer.
*Explicit is better than implicit.*

$S$ is a vector-subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and 
$V\cap W=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + S$. Hence, $V\cap W$ is an affine subspace.